# Integrate Paytm with swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, paytm

I want to integrate `paytm` payment gateway with `swift 3.0`.I just follow `github` [link](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit) . but i have probelm in `["CHECKSUMHASH"]`= "" . What can i put in this key.

```
orderDict["MID"] = strMid
                            orderDict["ORDER_ID"] = strOrderId
                            orderDict["CUST_ID"] = strCustomerId
                            orderDict["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = strIndustryType
                            orderDict["CHANNEL_ID"] = strChanalID
                            orderDict["TXN_AMOUNT"] = strAmt
                            orderDict["WEBSITE"] = strWebsite
                            orderDict["CALLBACK_URL"] = "http://xxxxx.co.in/verifyChecksum.php"
                    orderDict["CHECKSUMHASH"] = ""
```

This gives me invalid checksum please tell me how can i generate checksum.

Comment: Any reason you are not doing what it states in the documentation?

Comment: Can you please provide me github link for PayTM payment gateway because i need to implement payTM gateway in my APP

Comment: @KhushbuDesai Did you find any link which shows steps for integrating paytm in app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you can call your server api for generate checksum. If you are using `Almofire` then call

```
var parameters:[String:String]?
        parameters = ["MID":strMid,"ORDER_ID":strOrderId ,"INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID":strIndustryType,"CHANNEL_ID":strChanalID,"TXN_AMOUNT":strAmt,"WEBSITE":strWebsite, "CUST_ID":strCustomerId,"CALLBACK_URL":"http://xxxxxxx.co.in/verifyChecksum.php"]
                    showHud(self.view)
        print(parameters)

        Alamofire.request("http://xxxxxx.co.in/generateChecksum.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters,encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {}
```

Please pass **all** `parameter` in this api . It gives below `response`

```
{
  "CHECKSUMHASH": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "ORDER_ID": "xxxxxxxx",
  "payt_STATUS": "1"
}
```

In this `Dictionary` you get `CHECKSUMHASH` It Pass into `paytm order`.

Comment: From where can we get `verifyChecksum.php` and `generateChecksum.php` ?

Comment: You can download from this link https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_App_Checksum_Kit_PHP @MrugeshTank

Comment: ORDER_ID always returns null...any idea?

Comment: are you sending in `http://xxxxxx.co.in/generateChecksum.php` this request. Please give me code sample@Elangovan

Comment: @VinodKumar can we got successful transaction if json format not similar as yours?

Answer (score 1):

For integrating PayTm in swift you app you can find [this](https://github.com/ruchinsomal/PayTmIntegrationSwift) link on github.

Comment: do you have working example of paytm or paytm SDK? for objective c?

Comment: No, I have a working example of swift Which I have share in above link

Comment: this example is not working properly can you run and check your project once?

Comment: I have implemented in my project and it is working fine can you please check with your backend guy for generation of checksum